# "Add Service Reference" reference.svcmap and ServiceReference.ClientConfig empty

Tags: wcf, silverlight, web-services

I have an ASMX service that I wan't to add to my Silverlight project (in the near future this will be converted to a WCF service).

When using the "Add (or Update) Service Reference" not all the files seem to be created and files under Reference.svcmap aren't created and the ServiceReferences.ClientConfig is empty.

Has anyone ever come across this before?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I have a good answer for this one. I see this every so often. Usually the problem can be traced by looking at the output window entires that occured during the attempted proxy generation.

Sometimes it is caused because invalid or unsupported Wsdl or just some silly issue with serialization of one of the types.

Answer (score -1):

Try to give your client (Silverlight) application the WSDL, not just the ASMX when adding the service reference.
e.g. http://myserver.com/services/mywebservice.asmx?wsdl

Remove the service reference altogether from your client project, and try adding it again this time with the WSDL.

Comment: -1: actually, if you "give it the .asmx", it will go get the WSDL.